# Can VMs offload checksum calculations to the physical NIC when I disable checksum offload on the host?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

Due to random issues during backup, we were advised to disable checksum offload on all physical and virtual machines involved in the backup procedure.

I started by disabling the feature on all Hyper-V hosts and the target storage server, but I still see random failing backups.

Do I need to also disable this feature on all guests to check if this feature has an impact on our issue?

Comment: This is the recommendation of the backup vendor? I'd be wary of any suggestion from a software vendor to make changes to system components in order to make their software work, unless they show you supporting data and evidence proving their recommendation. That being said, if you're going to test this recommendation I'd recommend starting at one layer and working your way out from there rather than changing it at every layer en masse (Host, storage, VM). Why not start by re-enabling it on your storage and your hosts and  changing it on a few of the failing VM's only and seeing what happens?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Yes, this recommendation is coming from the vendor. I've heard the same recommendation previously from other vendors, directly from Microsoft and also from hardware vendors when we were troubleshooting issues in that network. I'm not quite sure how re-enabling the settings now would give me any more insights. I see failures now and I would see failures then. If I disable offload on 1 VM, it could take weeks until I see a failure. How long should I wait until I can reach a conclusion? If the feature is fully disabled everywhere, I could reach a conclusion much faster.

Comment: That being said, it seems like one can [adjust task offloading via the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Which makes this task a lot easier. So the question will probably be redundant soon.

Answer (score 0):

If not using [VT-d and VT-c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel-VT-d), the guest VM should have no direct access to the underlying network device, so it can not perform TCP offload without host intervention.

Anyway, it will cost you nothing to disable it even on guest VM, just for a try.

Comment: Well, it will cost a lot of time going through each VM and changing the settings in their NIC driver. If it won't make a difference, I'd like to avoid it. Especially since, if it doesn't make a difference, then I'd have to change it back.

Comment: I don't know how many VMs you manage, but if you can replicate the problem with only a small subset of VMs you can try to work on them only.